# Get the __dict__ representation of the parent class from a child class instance in Python

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I have the following code snippet:

```
@dataclass
class Parent:
  attr1: str
  attr2: str


@dataclass
class Child(Parent):
  attr3: str = None
  attr4: int = None
  attr5: int = None


data = Child(
  attr1 = "foo",
  attr2 = "bar",
)

print(data.__dict__)
```

This produces the following output:

```
{'attr1': 'foo', 'attr2': 'bar', 'attr3': None, 'attr4': None, 'attr5': None}
```

I want to develop a simple solution to get the dict representation of the parent class from the same class instance, so that the output is:

```
{'attr1': 'foo', 'attr2': 'bar'}
```

Do you have recommendations for a pythonic way of implementing this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you elaborate on why you would want to do this? If you really need this functionality, what's wrong with manually constructing a dictionary with the desired members?

Comment: Sure thing. I want to write the data to two different tables by using the same object. The first table should only contain the attributes of the parent class, the second one also the attributes of the child class.
Manually constructing a dictionary would be an option, but I've been searching for a robust way of doing this, which automatically adapts changes in the dataclasses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
parent_attrs = set(data.__dict__.keys()) - set(data.__class__.__dict__.keys())
print({k: data.__dict__[k] for k in parent_attrs})
```

Output:

```
{'attr2': 'bar', 'attr1': 'foo'}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer! Still more complicated than I thought it would be, but I think my use case is pretty unusual ...